# What is the difference between isSalable() and isAvailable()?

Tags: magento-1.7, product

What is the difference between isSalable() and isAvailable() ? Are these functions differ for each product types? Any clarification will be appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isAvailable()` only exists on products:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php:1259
\Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::isAvailable
public function isAvailable()
{
    return $this->getTypeInstance(true)->isSalable($this);
}
```

`isSalable` exists on product types and checks a lot of things.

- Product need to be enabled to be salable
- Configurables and bundles need to have at least one salable simple product.
- Downloadables need to have at least one link.